# Java: addressing "Unchecked Overriding" like errors

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make a representation of a domain of arbitrary values. So far I have these definitions:

```
public interface IDomainValue<V extends Comparable<V>> extends Comparable<IDomainValue<V>> {

    V getValue();

    UUID getDomainId();
}
```

```
public interface IFiniteDomain<V extends Comparable<V>, T extends IDomainValue<V>> {

    Iterable<T> getDomainValuesInSortedOrder();

    Iterable<T> getDomainValuesInRandomOrder();

    T getMin();
}
```

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DecimalDomain implements IFiniteDomain<Integer, DecimalDomain.DecimalDomainValue> {

    private static final int RAW_MIN = 0;

    private static final int RAW_MAX = 9;

    private static final UUID DOMAIN_ID = UUID.fromString(DecimalDomain.class.getName());

    // ImmutableList containing all domain values in sorted order.
    private static final ImmutableList<DecimalDomainValue> domainValues = ImmutableList.<DecimalDomainValue>builder()
            .addAll(IntStream.rangeClosed(RAW_MIN, RAW_MAX)
                    .boxed()
                    .sorted()
                    .map(val -> new DecimalDomainValue(val, DOMAIN_ID))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .build();

    public Iterable<DecimalDomainValue> getDomainValuesInSortedOrder() {
        return domainValues;
    }

    public Iterable<DecimalDomainValue> getDomainValuesInRandomOrder() {
        final List<DecimalDomainValue> shuffledDomainValues = new ArrayList<>(domainValues);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledDomainValues, sourceOfRandomness);
        return shuffledDomainValues;
    }

 
    public DecimalDomainValue getMin() {
        return domainValues.get(RAW_MIN);
    }
  
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class DecimalDomainValue implements IDomainValue<Integer> {

        @Getter
        private final Integer value;

        @Getter
        private final UUID domainId;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            // Implementation of equals here.
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(IDomainValue<Integer> dv) {
            // Implementation of compareTo here.
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a few alternatives: IDomainValue<?> getMin(), <T extends IDomainValue<? extends Comparable>> T getMin(), among a few others, but can never resolve all of the type warnings/errors.

Effectively, I want to be able to iterate over values in my domain, as well as perform comparisons between them, without knowing the type V in V extends Comparable down the line. More specifically, I am working on a CSP solver where each variable in the CSP may have a different finite domain, and being able to iterate over possible values that this CSP variable can take (without having to know the type) would be useful to implement a backtracking-based solver.

My interface for CSP variables looks like

```
public interface IProblemVariable<V extends Comparable<V>, T extends IDomainValue<V>> {

    IFiniteDomain<V, T> getDomain();

    Optional<T> getValue();

    void assignValue(T newValue);

    void clearValue();

    boolean isAssigned();
}
```

How should I set these up? Ideally, it would be simpler if I can avoid parameterizing IFiniteDomain/DecimalDomain. If I parameterize IFiniteDomain, then this seems to lead to needing a parameterization of the CSP solver, but each variable in the CSP could have a different domain.

---- Edit ----

A few additional snippets:

```
    private SearchBasedCSPEngine(@Nonnull final Collection<IProblemVariable<?, ?>> problemVariables,
                                 @Nonnull final Collection<IProblemConstraint> problemConstraints) {
        vars = new HashSet<>(problemVariables);
        constraints = new HashSet<>(problemConstraints);

        unassignedProblemVariables = problemVariables.stream()
                .filter(v -> !v.isAssigned())
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));


        // Error cannot infer arguments for HashSet
        candidateValues = unassignedProblemVariables.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(v -> v, v -> new HashSet<>(v.getDomain().getDomainValuesInRandomOrder())));
    }
```

```
        IProblemVariable<?, ?> var = unassignedProblemVariables.poll();

        List<?> possibleDomainValues = new LinkedList<>(candidateValues.get(var));

        // Error here as well.
        var.assignValue(possibleDomainValues.get(0));
```

Comment: "it would be simpler if I can avoid parameterizing `IFiniteDomain`" Parameterising `IFiniteDomain` is *exactly* what you should do! `V` and `T` belongs to `IFiniteDomain`, and `DecimalDomain implements IFiniteDomain<Integer, DecimalDomainValue>`. I understand that you can't compare them directly if you don't know `V` and just have a `IFiniteDomain<?, ?>`, but if I understand your situation correctly, the wildcard can be [captured](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) with a helper method.

Comment: I'd suggest that you [edit] your question to include details about exactly what you are trying to do with the domain - show how exactly you are going to "iterate over values in my domain, as well as perform comparisons between them".

Comment: I have added a few details. Essentially, I am working on a CSP solver where each variable in the CSP may have a different finite domain, and being able to iterate over possible values that this CSP variable can take (without having to know the underlying type V) would be useful to implement a backtracking-based solver.

Comment: "but each variable in the CSP could have a different domain" And this is *fine*. You'd have an `List<IProblemVariable<?, ?>>`, right? We are slowly getting to a solvable problem here. I'm guessing you are looping through the `List<IProblemVariable<?, ?>>`, and trying to compare the values in each of the domains, and getting an error?

Comment: Yes. I have included a couple of examples of things I am trying to do. When I add wildcards, it becomes much more difficult to work with these values.

Comment: The error in the constructor is not actually related to wildcards. If `getDomainValuesInRandomOrder` returns a `Collection<T>`, it will work. There is no `HashSet` constructor that takes `Iterable<T>` :-)

Comment: You're right. That was careless on my end when trying to produce a MWE.

Comment: Okay, now that I have a better picture of your situation, the conclusion is that you have to do some (unchecked) cast *somewhere*. Either in the solver, if you decide to parameterise everything, or in the domains if you don't parameterise it. The map that you are using is inherently not type safe. There are many similar questions about doing this kind of "type associations" in a map actually, but you just can't do that without an unchecked cast.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is requiring an unchecked cast somewhere a sign that the design is inadequate in some way?